# Do we want hats?

Tags: discussion, marketing

Last year around Christmas time [arQAde](http://gaming.stackexchange.com) had an awesome promotion in which they awarded hats for gravatars for completing basic tasks around the site. If you don't remember it, here is a [link](http://stackexchange.com/promos/2/hat-dash) the promo from last year (and [another!](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/)).

[image: hats]

This year, SE is planning to run it for *everyone* because we all love hats, right? right?

But to get this awesome hat promotion we have to **opt in**. That means acting on this meta post, whether that's voting it up, answering in the affirmative, positive comments and/or just directing positive energy this direction.

I (and the other mods I hope) think this is a great opportunity for us to grow and get even more awesome content.

HOWEVER: this promotion is **optional** for sites, and/or individual users. If the users of this site *do not* want this in general feel free to voice that opinion. We can opt out of the promotion. Individual users will be able to opt out as well (they will be provided with an "I hate Hats" link to opt out).

Again, please let us know what you think as this is your site not ours.

Comment: [The above post comes from 100% recycled content.](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1420/do-you-like-hats)

Comment: But ***of course!*** Hats are the best! (But I'm 1000000% biased.)

Comment: On all the other sites I upvoted instantly, but on this one I am … skeptical. (pun absolutely not intended)

Comment: **Hats requested**

Comment: yes please, need hats :)

Answer (score 11):

Personally I’d prefer a **Fez**.

[image]

… But ya, why not?

Comment: If I could upvote this post a thousand times, I would!!!!!!

Comment: Everyone must wear Fez's and like it!

Answer (score 11):

As long as there is a tin-foil hat, of course.

[image: Free your mind]

Comment: There was no tin foil hat. :(

Answer (score 4):

I'm not convinced that I, personally, want a hat avatar.

But if "bah humbug" people like me can easily opt out, then I have no objections, so I vote yes.

Comment: Yes, opting out should be very simple! And, you'll neither see hats nor be seen sporting one.

Comment: I propose a Grinch hat for you, Mr. Humbug!

Answer (score 3):

I vote yes.  Especially if I can get a Fez!

Answer (score 3):

Make mine a Bowler, or perhaps a swanky Fedora plsthx