# Do we want hats '14

Tags: discussion

As has been customary in [past years](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1990/do-we-want-hats/1992#1992) stackexchange are running  the usual winterbash with hats!

If you've not experienced this before [here's some more reading](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/winter-bash-2013-is-here/)

So the question is, do we want hats for '14 on skeptics?

Comment: So, Santa Lucia?

Answer (score 11):

## Yes!

Because fez's are cool!

Comment: Can I get a bowtie too?

Comment: I want a pirate hat with a skull 'n crossbones. AVAST, YE SCURVY CORPORATE SWABS! PREPARE TO BE BOARDED!!!!

Comment: @BobJarvis But Boba Fett was a pirate, in the manner of his time...

Comment: Shouldn't it be "fezzes"?

Comment: @Ilya Perhaps "feza"? :)

Answer (score 10):

Hats are a must if you want to prevent the government of Lizard People from reading your mind.

Also, users can opt out of it if they don't like hats.

[image: hat]

Comment: The day we can have custom hats the tin-foil hat must be ours!